# Decode react native firebase Crashlytics stack trace

Tags: react-native, crashlytics, stack-trace, react-native-firebase

I'm using firebase crashlytics with my react native app version `0.71.4`, and I've this stack trace from crashlytics console:

```
Non-fatal Exception: io.invertase.firebase.crashlytics.a: undefined is not a function
       at .<unknown>(pendingPhotos =-)
       at .HomeWithPendingPhotos(address at index.android.bundle:1:1954251)
       at .renderWithHooks(address at index.android.bundle:1:326471)
       at .updateFunctionComponent(address at index.android.bundle:1:332734)
       at .beginWork$1(address at index.android.bundle:1:366817)
       at .performUnitOfWork(address at index.android.bundle:1:353802)
       at .workLoopSync(address at index.android.bundle:1:353705)
       at .renderRootSync(address at index.android.bundle:1:353589)
       at .performSyncWorkOnRoot(address at index.android.bundle:1:351077)
       at .flushSyncCallbacks(address at index.android.bundle:1:316168)
       at .scheduleUpdateOnFiber(address at index.android.bundle:1:348540)
       at .dispatchSetState(address at index.android.bundle:1:330186)
       at .?anon_0_(address at index.android.bundle:1:2306425)
       at .next((native):0:0)
       at .asyncGeneratorStep(address at index.android.bundle:1:83513)
       at ._next(address at index.android.bundle:1:83784)
       at .tryCallOne(InternalBytecode.js:53:16)
       at .anonymous(InternalBytecode.js:139:27)
       at .apply((native):0:0)
       at .anonymous(address at index.android.bundle:1:230757)
       at ._callTimer(address at index.android.bundle:1:229754)
       at ._callReactNativeMicrotasksPass(address at index.android.bundle:1:229918)
       at .callReactNativeMicrotasks(address at index.android.bundle:1:231837)
       at .__callReactNativeMicrotasks(address at index.android.bundle:1:100935)
       at .anonymous(address at index.android.bundle:1:100076)
       at .__guard(address at index.android.bundle:1:100812)
       at .flushedQueue(address at index.android.bundle:1:99987)
       at .callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue(address at index.android.bundle:1:99843)
```

First I removed lines with native inside e.g ( `at .next((native):0:0)`, `at .apply((native):0:0)` )

And I followed steps from [Symbolicating a stack trace](https://reactnative.dev/docs/symbolication), and run this command

```
./android/app/build/intermediates/sourcemaps/react/release/index.android.bundle.packager.map < trace.txt
```

But I got result of null null null:

```
Non-fatal Exception: io.invertase.firebase.crashlytics.a: undefined is not a function
       at .<unknown>(pendingPhotos =-)
       at .HomeWithPendingPhotos(address at null:null:null)
       at .renderWithHooks(address at null:null:null)
       at .updateFunctionComponent(address at null:null:null)
       at .beginWork$1(address at null:null:null)
       at .performUnitOfWork(address at null:null:null)
       at .workLoopSync(address at null:null:null)
       at .renderRootSync(address at null:null:null)
       at .performSyncWorkOnRoot(address at null:null:null)
       at .flushSyncCallbacks(address at null:null:null)
       at .scheduleUpdateOnFiber(address at null:null:null)
       at .dispatchSetState(address at null:null:null)
```

I also tried [stack-beautifier](https://github.com/software-mansion-labs/stack-beautifier)

```
stack-beautifier ./android/app/build/intermediates/sourcemaps/react/release/index.android.bundle.packager.map -t trace.txt
```

But I got result of unknown:

```
Non-fatal Exception: io.invertase.firebase.crashlytics.a: undefined is not a function
  at <unknown>
  at <unknown>
  at <unknown>
  at <unknown>
  at <unknown>
  at <unknown>
  at <unknown>
  at <unknown>
  at <unknown>
  at <unknown>
  at <unknown>
  at <unknown>
  at <unknown>
  at <unknown>
  at ./s/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:179:2
  at ./s/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:296:2
  at <unknown>
  at <unknown>
  at <unknown>
  at <unknown>
  at <unknown>
  at <unknown>
  at <unknown>
  at <unknown>
  at <unknown>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using following
android

```
npx metro-symbolicate index.android.bundle.map < stacktrace.txt
```

ios

```
npx metro-symbolicate main.jsbundle.map < stacktrace.txt
```

if your stacktrace file contain following then remove it
[native code] or :0:0 in my stacktrace from Crashlytics

Comment: index.android.bundle.map > I'm using `index.android.bundle.packager.map` generated by build release.

I also removed the [native] lines as I explained

Comment: did you found result ?

Comment: no! same result bro